# After pulling from master by chance I pressed ctrl+z and

Tags: git, github

After pulling from  master by chance I pressed  ctrl+z and all changes lost and when I again pull from master it is saying already updated can I undo them

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/7976758

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore all file  not staged with:

```
git checkout .
```

If you don't press `save` or Ctrl+S. Just press Ctrl+Shift+Z to undo. Or just close it file without save

Comment: it is saying   "Updated 0 paths from the index"

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+Z or close the file without save